# How to send 200 curl requests in specific one second of time in Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, json

First of all let me explain my problem and what I am going to do. I would like to post 200 curl requests (the response of them is not important) to an API of my web server only in one second and specific which is 30. I try this with the following code

```
    mycurl() { curl -Z 'https://mywebserver/' -H 'Accept: application/json' --data-binary '{"JSON"}' ;};
   export -f mycurl;
   while [  $(gdate +%S%N) -gt 29500000000 -o $(gdate +%S%N) -lt 30500000000 ]; do mycurl; done
```

When I execute this code only 6x of my curl will send to the server in the mentioned time how can increase this to 200 requests? Of course I prefer 200 of requests arrived at my web server in the same time.

Comment: You can only send as many requests simultaneouslyas your network connection can handle. It's very likely it cannot handle 200 requests within one second. 
Also, since the scenario of sending many requests in little time sounds very similar to an attempt of DDoS, I would like to hear more about your reasons of doing this.

Comment: You likely won't be able to do this using a script and multiple processes... try looking for a utility that is designed specifically for stressing HTTP servers. Be careful about requiring requests to arrive "_at the same time_" - computers are probably much faster than you might think!

Comment: @JohannesH. You are right and I am avoid of doing some things similar to DDoS. I thought it could be easy do that as I need only 200 requests which is too small. The reason I am doing that is my api function will sort the requests with the time they will arrive and I would like to test this.

Comment: @Attie What kind of utility? I do not want send thousand of requests that 200 will success. Only 200 requests is enough. Could you please ket me know some of this utility?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to send 200 requests at the same time, easy.  Just use:

```
mycurl() {
  curl -Z 'https://mywebserver/' -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  --data-binary '{"JSON"}' &
};
export -f mycurl;

for $((COUNT=1; COUNT<=200; COUNT++)); do mycurl; done
```

This starts the `curl` processes in the background and allows them to run simultaneously.  It will almost certainly complete in less than a second, however!